# Is there a function in Python that checks the number of printouts of the output?

Tags: python, xcode

Is there a function in Python that checks the number of printouts of the output?
for example if i want to know how many times the word "avi" is printing in the output...

```
def print_avi():
    for i in range(0, 173):
        print("avi")

print_avi()
```

or in the next code:

```
def print_avi():
    for i in range(0, 2019, 2):
        print("avi")

print_avi()
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. If you want to count something in Python you should write code to do that.

Here's an example:

```
def print_avi():
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, 173):
        print("avi")
        count += 1
    return count


avi_count = print_avi()
print("avi count:", avi_count)
```